# How to move a camera in Blender 2.61 with Python

Tags: python, blender, blender-2.61

I'm searching for a simple script to move a camera in Blender 2.61 with Python.
I thought this would be an easy task, but the Camera object has no properties like loc or something similar.

I only found scripts online for Blender 2.49 but they don't work anymore because of the immense API changes with Blender 2.5.

I would appreciate any hints.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A [friendly user on reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/ohvx4/so_question_how_to_move_a_camera_in_blender_261/c3he3c7) pointed me to one correct solution: The trick is to retrieve the camera as an `Object`, not as a `Camera`. With this way, you can set the location via the standard way and set keyframes.

If you want to set `Camera` specific objects, you have to retrieve it via `bpy.data.cameras`.

```
import bpy

if(len(bpy.data.cameras) == 1):
    obj = bpy.data.objects['Camera'] # bpy.types.Camera
    obj.location.x = 0.0
    obj.location.y = -10.0
    obj.location.z = 10.0
    obj.keyframe_insert(data_path="location", frame=10.0)
    obj.location.x = 10.0
    obj.location.y = 0.0
    obj.location.z = 5.0
    obj.keyframe_insert(data_path="location", frame=20.0)
```

Answer (score 16):

furtelwart's answer was quite usefull. I did some more digging so you can also set some other very usefull properties regarding the camera and render.

```
import bpy

tx = 0.0
ty = 0.0
tz = 80.0

rx = 0.0
ry = 0.0
rz = 0.0

fov = 50.0

pi = 3.14159265

scene = bpy.data.scenes["Scene"]

# Set render resolution
scene.render.resolution_x = 480
scene.render.resolution_y = 359

# Set camera fov in degrees
scene.camera.data.angle = fov*(pi/180.0)

# Set camera rotation in euler angles
scene.camera.rotation_mode = 'XYZ'
scene.camera.rotation_euler[0] = rx*(pi/180.0)
scene.camera.rotation_euler[1] = ry*(pi/180.0)
scene.camera.rotation_euler[2] = rz*(pi/180.0)

# Set camera translation
scene.camera.location.x = tx
scene.camera.location.y = ty
scene.camera.location.z = tz
```

I'm using this script to make batch rendering. You can check it out here:
http://code.google.com/p/encuadro/source/browse/renders/marker/model/marker_a4.py

It will be improved later to take command line arguments. I'm new to python and blender so this may be kind of amateur but it works.

Comment: Please check out my recent question for the command line arguments in the python script since i'm having some trouble there. Maybe you can help. Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667314/python-script-with-arguments-for-command-line-blender

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the camera rigs at the [bottom of this page](http://www.blendernation.com/2010/09/13/free-rigs-for-blender-2-5/) could be a nice starting point.