# Transfer values from bash to python script

Tags: python, linux, bash, command-line

I have script in bash called "[Nautilus Script](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NautilusScriptsHowto)". It can be executed from system folders, for making custom operations with selected files:

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
    file=$1
    #doing smf with selected file
    shift
done
```

Аlso, I know about ability launch Blender in cmd, with custom python scripts:

```
blender -b blendfile.blend -P script.py -x 1 -F PNG -f 1
```

And I whant to take a value `file` and transfer it into python script to use it in `script.py`:

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
    file=$1
    blender -b blendfile.blend -P script.py//+put here $file// -x 1 -F PNG -f 1     
    shift
done
```

how can I do this?

About [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255898/how-to-iterate-over-arguments-in-a-bash-script): *Note, python script launches in blender, not in bash shell*

Comment: Are you trying to say that `blender -b blendfile.blend -P script.py "$1" -x 1 -F PNG -f 1` inside the loop does not do what you are asking?

Comment: @tripleee answer from Nils Werner works. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667314/python-script-with-arguments-for-command-line-blender) explanes why this simple way doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [blender.stackexchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6817/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-blender-python-script)

Blender ignores all arguments after a `--`, Python doesn't. You can search for `--` in Python and read all arguments after it using

```
import sys
argv = sys.argv
argv = argv[argv.index("--") + 1:]  # get all args after "--"
```

The arguments you would be passing in then look like

```
blender -b blendfile.blend -P script.py -x 1 -F PNG -f 1 -- $file
```