# Blender: how to move the camera from python script

Tags: python, blender

Here is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865672/how-to-move-a-camera-in-blender-2-61-with-python). But the answer uses euler angles instead of setting the i,j,k base coordinates in the cam's model matrix.
I'd like to set the camera's orientation by its i,j,k coordinates (these are the coordinates in the model matrix which sets the object's orientation and scaling).
What is the Blender python API for doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blender's [mathutils module](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/mathutils.html) is used to work with matrices. To transform any object using a matrix you set the [objects `matrix_world`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.matrix_world) property.

```
import bpy
import mathutils
import math

mat_loc = mathutils.Matrix.Translation((2.0, 3.0, 4.0))
mat_sca = mathutils.Matrix.Scale(0.5, 4, (0.0, 0.0, 1.0))
mat_rot = mathutils.Matrix.Rotation(math.radians(45.0), 4, 'X')
mat_comb = mat_loc * mat_rot * mat_sca

cam = bpy.data.objects['Camera']
cam.matrix_world = mat_comb
```

Comment: In Blender 2.8+ this does not work anymore. To fix this simply replace  *  with @
Source:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129473/typeerror-element-wise-multiplication-not-supported-between-matrix-and-vect#129474